# Get the very last part of a Url to use in a ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I've very new to C# and I'm using ASP.NET 6.

On a .cshtml Razor page I'm trying to use a ternary operator to fill in a HTML  element class based on the very last segment of a URL pathname. So for example: On a page called **localhost:7659/Identity/Account/Login**
I'm trying to test if a loaded URL page name has the word **Login** in the very last URL segment.

This is what I'm trying at present:

```
<a class="@Context.Request.Path == '/Login' ? 'active-page' : ''" href="/Identity/Account/Login">
```

But the above is rendered as

```
<a class="/Identity/Account/Login == '/Login' ? 'active-page-header-menu-link' : ''" href="/Identity/Account/Login">
```

ie the code is not being parsed out, also `@Context.Request.Path` is returning the whole URL pathname, in this case, **/Identity/Account/Login** how can I just return the value **Login**?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generated html is also not correct, you need use `@(...)` in the anchor class.

Change your code to:

```
<a class="@(Context.Request.Path.Value.IndexOf("/Login")>-1? "active-page" : "")" href="/Identity/Account/Login">XXX</a>
```

Then it will generate the link if the request url last segment is `Login`:

```
<a class="active-page" href="/Identity/Account/Login">XXX</a>
```

If the last segment is not `Login`, it will generate the link:

```
<a class href="/Identity/Account/Login">XXX</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the path contains 'login', like:

```
Context.Request.Path.contains("Login")
```

Or use the below code to get the last part of the URL:

```
Context.Request.Path.Substring(Context.Request.Path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```